# How to update the canvas in python using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I need to update my canvas but tkinter.update() says tkinter has no attribute "update". What might be the possible solution. My thanks in advance.

Comment: Preferable when you ask a question you should provide testable code. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `update` on your `canvas` object instead of `tkinter`, i.e. `canvas.update()`.

Comment: note: it doesn't have to be the canvas object, it can be any widget. It just can't be the tkinter module object.